# forms deprecated error with RC5

Tags: angular

Error:"It looks like you're using the old forms module. This will be opt-in in the next RC, and will eventually be removed in favor of the new forms module."

Why am I getting this error?  Where is documentation for new forms interface?

Why do I need the following when I am using FormsModule?

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()
]);


         <form *ngIf="postingMessage">
        <h3>New Message</h3>
        <label>Subject:</label><br>
        <input [(ngModel)]="postingMessage.subject" 
        class="form-control"
        type="text" 
        id="subject"
        required
        autofocus
        size="80"
        [ngClass]="{invalid: subject.touched && !subject.valid}"
        name="subject" #subject="ngModel"><br>
        <div [hidden]="subject.valid || subject.pristine" 
         class="alert alert-danger">
        Subject is required
        </div>
        <label>Message:</label><br>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="postingMessage.body" rows="10" cols="80" 
        name="name" ></textarea>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE : docs seem to be missing or not completed yet.**

In ***RC5***, new ***[NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)*** has been introduced.

**[You can learn form with NgModule implementation here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)**

**[breaking changes in RC5](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**

**Before:**

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from @angular/forms;

bootstrap(App, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms()
]);
```

**After:**

```
import {DeprecatedFormsModule} from @angular/common;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, DeprecatedFormsModule],
  bootstrap:  [MyComponent],
})
export class MyAppModule{}
```